# ClassCastException Integer to Double

Tags: java, classcastexception

Why this code throws this exception:

```
public class DS3{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double r = (double)((Object)4);
        System.out.println(r);          
    }   
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

And this, just run fine:

```
public class DS4{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double r = (double)(4);
            System.out.println(r);          
        }   
    }
```

Both are a attempt to convert integer to double, right?

Comment: `4` is automatically boxed to `Integer`, which cannot be casted to `double`.

Comment: Just as a hint, `4` can also be a double without casting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Both are a attempt to convert integer to double, right?

Yes, and no.

This line

```
double r = (double)((Object)4);
```

causes the compiler to box the `4` in an `Integer`, and an `Integer` can't be cast to a double.

The bytecode for this snippet:

```
(double)((Object) 4)
```

Looks as follows:

```
// ...
5: iconst_4
6: invokestatic  #2    // Method Integer.valueOf
9: checkcast     #3    // class java/lang/Double
// ...
```

(Line 6 causes the boxing, line 9 throws the exception.)

In other words, it's equivalent to

```
Object tmp = (Object) 4;  // Auto-boxing to Integer
double d = (double) tmp;  // Illegal cast from Integer to double.
```

Here on the other hand

```
double r = (double)(4);
```

`4` is regarded as an ordinary `int`, which *can* be cast to a `double`.

Answer (score 5):

The two conversions that you show, namely,

```
Object x = 4;
double r = (double)x;
```

and

```
double r = (double)(4);
```

require a different number of conversions:

- The second conversion needs a single cast from an `int` to a `double`,
- The first conversion needs an unboxing conversion from `Object` followed by a cast.

Java cast operator performs only one conversion at a time.

To make the first conversion work you have to add another cast to `Integer`, like this ([demo](http://ideone.com/5u1hWR)):

```
double r = (double)((Integer)((Object)4));
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `4` is autoboxed to an `Integer`, which cannot then be cast to a primitive `double`.

Perhaps what you want is simply:

```
double r = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt converts 4 into an object of type `Integer` which basically is a container that holds the `int` value of 4.

The second attempt just casts a `int` into a `double` with both being primitive non-object types.

You can't cast an object into a primitive type.

Comment: You can cast an `Object` to a primitive type, as long as it's the right type. `Object o = 1; int a = (int) o;` works.

Comment: It would be best not to cast Objects as primitives. Defeats the purpose of using Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is about boxing and unboxing. You can read more about that here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html